# Authenticate with Exchange to access email inbox with imaplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, oauth, imaplib

I have a python script that used to login to an outlook inbox:

```py
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL

imap = IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
imap.login("user", "password")
```

It now fails with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imap.py", line 4, in <module>
    imap.login("user", "password")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imaplib.py", line 603, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: b'LOGIN failed.'
```

Microsoft has [disabled basic authentication for Exchange Online](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-time-s-up/ba-p/3695312). How should I authenticate now that basic auth has been deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

In order to authenticate with OAUTH2 you [need an existing app registration in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app). I am assuming you already have this set up.

#### Add Exchange API permissions to the application

1. From within your app registration page, click **API permissions** along the left menu.
2. Check if the **Configured permissions** section has the *Office 365 Exchange Online* API. If it does, you can skip to the next section:
   [image: Configured permissions]
3. Click the **Add a permission** button above the table. Select the **APIs my organization uses** tab and search for *Office 365 Exchange Online*:
   [image: Office 365 Exchange Online]
4. Select **Application permissions** for the type, enable the **IMAP.AccessAsApp** permission. Then click the **Add permissions** button.
   [image: Permissions Name]

**NOTE:** An admin may [need to approve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#how-to-grant-consent-if-you-registered-the-application-for-your-own-tenent) the permission. They also may need to [set up the Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#register-service-principals-in-exchange) (there is one [unclear step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74131277/3903479) to be aware of).

---

#### Request access token

1. From within your app registration page, click **Certificates & secrets** along the left menu.
2. Select the **Client Secrets** tab and click the **New client secret** button. Fill out the form and click **Add**.
3. Copy the *Value* for the secret. Click **Overview** in the left menu and copy the *Application (client) ID* and *Directory (tenant) ID*. Use these variables in your script to make a POST request to the OAUTH2 endpoint:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests

tenant = "Directory (tenant) ID"
url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
payload = urlencode({
    "client_id": "Application (client) ID",
    "client_secret": "Secret Value",
    "scope": "https://outlook.com/.default",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
```

**NOTE:** Scope is important! I had to use `https://outlook.com/.default`. I've seen some documentation use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` or `https://ps.outlook.com/.default`, neither of which have access to authenticating with the IMAP server.

---

#### Use access token to authenticate

Change the `imap.login` call to `imap.authenticate`:

```py
imap.authenticate(
    "XOAUTH2",
    lambda _: f"user={email}\1auth=Bearer {access_token}\1\1".encode()
)
```

The second parameter expects bytes, so I `encode` the formatted string.